# How to Zoom .DAE 3D model using ARKit iOS

Tags: arkit, scnnode, scnscene, arscnview

I have a 3D model with .scn extension. How to zoom it with pinch gesture without **virtualobject** file from iOS sample Placing Objects application.

Pinch gesture works well with   .scn's if its converted from .obj file. But its not working with .dae model.

```
    func addPinchGestureToSceneView() {

        pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(scale))
        pinchGesture.scale = 1.0;
        pinchGesture.delegate = self
        self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
    }
  private func node(at position: CGPoint) -> SCNNode? {
        var hitTestOptions = [SCNHitTestOption: Any]()
        hitTestOptions[SCNHitTestOption.boundingBoxOnly] = true
        return sceneView.hitTest(position, options: hitTestOptions)
            .first(where: { self.getOnlyModelName(name: $0.node.name ?? "") == self.currentmodel.modelname})?
            .node

    }

 @objc func scale(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

        if self.currentmodel.isZoomEnabled == false{
            return
        }

        let location = gesture.location(in: sceneView)

        guard let node = node(at: location)else{return}

    //    guard let node = node(at: location) else  { return }

        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            originalScale = node.scale
            gesture.scale = CGFloat(node.scale.x)
            print("Begin:: \(originalScale)")
        case .changed:
            guard var originalScale = originalScale else { return }
            if gesture.scale > 2.0{
                return
            }
            originalScale.x = Float(gesture.scale)
            originalScale.y = Float(gesture.scale)
            originalScale.z = Float(gesture.scale)
            node.scale = originalScale
        case .ended:

            guard var originalScale = originalScale else { return }
            if gesture.scale > 2.0{
                return
            }
            originalScale.x = Float(gesture.scale)
            originalScale.y = Float(gesture.scale)
            originalScale.z = Float(gesture.scale)
            node.scale = originalScale
            gesture.scale = CGFloat(node.scale.x)

        default:
            gesture.scale = 1.0
            originalScale = nil
        }
```

Comment: Anything you tried? code?

Comment: provide a code for more detail.

Comment: maybe it is in how you load model. does your `node(at:)` return nil?

Comment: yes...some times node child of DAE root node

Answer (score 0):

When it's a dae, you might need to try to grab the parent of the node caught in the hit test. I had a similar issue with dae that got solved by getting the parent of the child, or even sometimes the grandparent of the child.

Comment: i am also facing same problem and i tried as per you answer parent node in hit test but not work , can you pleas share your code ?